# Verify a method is not been called anymore after cancellation

Tags: c#, moq

I have a test case where a method is been call inside an infinity loop, I want to create a test to assure that the method will not be called anymore after the cancelation token cancels, something like this:

```
[Test]
public void should_dequeue_work_items_until_stopped()
{
    // Act
    _sut.StartAsync(_cancellationToken.Token);
    _backgroundTaskQueue.Verify( o => o.DequeueAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()));
    _backgroundTaskQueue.VerifyNoOtherCalls();

    // Assert
    _sut.StopAsync(_cancellationToken.Token);
    _backgroundTaskQueue.NO_MORE_CALL_AFTER_LINE_ABOVE
}
```

The test code runs against something like this:

```
while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var workItem = await TaskQueue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

    try
    {
        await workItem(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.Logger.Error(
            ex, 
            $"Error occurred executing {nameof(workItem)}. The task was cancel");

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheGeneral I want to make sure after I call the cancelation token no other calls will be made

Comment: That would involve you invoking custom logic inside the method which prevents any execution post calling Cancel using the `Cancellation Token`, by checking the Token status. You can even use a thread safe variable, which gets updated on every execution and on no execution there's no further update, which can be checked in the `_backgroundTaskQueue.VerifyNoOtherCalls()`, this seems simple, am I missing something here. Also for high concurrency, you may just synchronize the checking part in the beginning